# IndexSizeError: The index is not in the allowed range for iPad

Tags: javascript, debugging, ipad

[image: code]

Expected behavior:
selection.getRangeAt(0) should no error.

Actual behavior:
IndexSizeError: The index is not in the allowed range.

Platforms:
Ipad

Works on:
Google, Safari

Hello. I'm confused on why this displays out the error for iPads but not for the browsers. Looking for any tips and advice.

I tried [getSelection not working properly in iOS 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52770900/getselection-not-working-properly-in-ios-12), but it displayed the same error.

Comment: Please don't share images of your code. Copy the code into the post instead.